# How do you get user input to decide how many elements are in a string array?

Tags: c#

I'm struggling to find a way to first

1. Get User input to decide how many elements will be in the next string array
2. Then to convert the Users input from string to int for the array
3. Is there also a way to display the element number along with the string element like so.... `Console.WriteLine(1. StringName  2.StringName);`

This is my code :

```
Console.WriteLine("How many countries you want mate ? ");
string numberOfCountries = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Please name your countries ");
string[] nameOfCountries = new string[10];

for (int i = 0; i < nameOfCountries.Length ; i++)
{
    nameOfCountries[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: What do you suppose that `string numberOfCountries = Console.ReadLine();` is there for?

Comment: If the problem is solved, mark the answer that helped you as the accepted answer (little checkmark) and give it an upvote.

Comment: Often easier / simpler to use a `List<string>` and ask for a blank input to finish the list.

Answer (score 1):

> Get User input to decide how many elements will be in the next string array

You can put a variable in when creating an array size, like this:

```
string[] nameOfCountries = new string[someVariable];
```

`someVariable` needs to be an `int`. `Console.WriteLine` returns a string, so you need to parse the string to an int. You can use `int.Parse` for that. So:

```
int numberOfCountries = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string[] nameOfCountries = new string[numberOfCountries];
```

Note that `Parse` will throw an exception if it isn't able to correctly parse the input in to an integer.

> Is there also a way to display the element number along with the string element

You can use a similar loop like you are when you are assigning values to the array.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, nameOfCountries[i]);
```

Comment: When i write 
   string[] nameOfCountries = new string[someVariable];
it prompts me with Error CS0029 , cannot convert int to string 
Any way to solve this ?

Comment: @keanu.b I had a mistake in my example code. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40643944/revisions) for the edit details.

Comment: Actually nevermind i figured it out , thanks for the help !!

Comment: Yeah no problem i changed it to an int eventually once i figured it out haha

Comment: Alternatively, use TryParse.

Answer (score 0):

Program:

```
string mate = "mate";

Console.WriteLine($"How many countries you want {mate}?");
string numberOfCountries = Console.ReadLine();
int numberOfCountriesInt;
while ( !int.TryParse( numberOfCountries, out numberOfCountriesInt ) )
{
    mate = mate.Insert(1, "a");
    Console.WriteLine($"How many countries you want {mate}?");
    numberOfCountries = Console.ReadLine();

}

Console.WriteLine("Please name your countries ");
string[] namesOfCountries = new string[numberOfCountriesInt];

for (int i = 0; i < namesOfCountries.Length; i++)
{
    namesOfCountries[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}

for (int i = 0; i < namesOfCountries.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i+1}, {namesOfCountries[i]}");
}
```

Output:

```
How many countries you want mate?
Two
How many countries you want maate?
Two?
How many countries you want maaate?
2
Please name your countries
Stralya
PNG
1. Stralya
2. PNG
```

---

Please note that a `List<string>` may be better to store data like this. Then you can do something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please name your countries ");
var namesOfCountries = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCountriesInt; i++)
{
     namesOfCountries.Add(Console.ReadLine());
}
```